# How to disable pivot tables reading for Workbook creation

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I use apache poi. I want to get object of Workbook class using following code.
Unfortunately WorkbookFactory tries to read pivot tables cache that causes error. Is it possible to disable reading pivot tables? How to do this in apache poi. Thank you for help in advance.

```
    try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputFile.getInputStream())) { ... }
```